# How to wrap loose variables and functions within a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, function, variables, firefox-addon

I try to submit a simple Firefox add-on and got a message from AMO editor about wrapping of variables and functions within a JavaScript object in order to prevent conflicts with other add-ons that may be installed by users. The working code is very simple and looks:

```
function analyze() {
    var uri = document.getElementById('urlbar').value;
    var requrl="http://www.myanalyzingsiteaddress.com/" + (uri);
    gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab(requrl);
}
```

Is it enough to make other **var** names to avoid eventual conflicts or could you point me to other code change, which would fulfill the AMO editor's instruction?

Thank you in advance!

Evgenij

Answer (score 0):

You should have been pointed to [Javascript Object Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/JavaScript_Object_Management) from the XUL School tutorial.

`analyze` is a generic name. In an overlay there is only one scope/namespace which is shared by the browser code itself and any additional extension code. It is therefore possible that either the browser or another add-on uses `analyze` as well and *boom*.

You need to avoid that by making names a specifc as possible. E.g.

- `function my_addon_id_analyze() ...`
- Use an an object with a (pseudo) unique name.

  ```
  if (!("org" in this)) {
    this.org = {};
  }
  if (!("example" in org)) {
    org.example = {};
  }
  org.example.addonid = {
    analyze: function() ...
  };
  // call
  org.example.addonid.analyze();
  ```
- Or even "hide" your code in an anonymous function. This is then hidden from the DOM as well, so no more `<button id="example.org.addonid.mybutton" onclick="analyze()">` event handling. But you can always use `addEventListener`.

  ```
  (function() {
  "use strict";
  function analyze() ...
  // wire up an event handler instead of onlick
  document.getElementById("example.org.addonid.mybutton").addEventListener("click", analyze);
  })();
  ```
- Mix some/all of the above, as long as you avoid short/generic names:

  ```
  if (!("org" in this)) {
    this.org = {};
  }
  if (!("example" in org)) {
    org.example = {};
  }
  org.example.addonid = (function() {
    function analyze() ...
    function notvisibleoutside() ...

    // return object of "exported"/"visible" functions.
    return {
      analyze: analyze
    };
  })();
  // call
  org.example.addonid.analyze()
  ```

Also, keep in mind that missing `var` (or `let`/`const`) declarations will implicitly declare the variable in the global scope.
E.g.:

```
function abc() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) doSomething();
}
```

Will implicitly declare a variable named `i` in the global scope (in a XUL window the global scope is `window`, therefore this will create `window.i`). Implicit declarations may therefore not only cause conflicts but also create quasi memory leaks, e.g.

```
function call_me_to_leak_1MB() {
  hugeArray = new ArrayBuffer(1<<20);
}
```

will declare `window.hugeArray` that lives as long as the browser window is open instead of using a local variable that gets garbage collected as soon as the variables goes out of scope (and there are no more other references, of course).

Using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) makes implicit declaration an error, which is helpful to catch and avoid such mistakes early.

So much for the Javascript part. There is still other stuff that might clash.

- DOM Ids: Use unique `<button id="example.org.addonid.mybutton">`, or more CSS friendly `<button id="example-org-addonid-mybutton">` (or at the very least something like `addonid-mybutton`) instead of `<button id="mybutton">`
- CSS: Never style random elements.

  - No: `button { color: green; }`
  - Yep: `#example-org-addonid-mybutton { color: green; }`
- chrome.manifest:

  - No: `content generic content/`
  - Yep: `content example-org-addonid content/`.